# Assertion is started before request in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a problem that when i run below code

```
cy.contains("Lion").click();

cy.get('rows').each((row) => {
expect(row.text()).to.include("Lion");
});
```

The assertion above is run before the request that is done after:  `cy.contains("Lion").click();` is executed which will fail the application. The request is done using graphQL

Answer (score 1):

So first there is no property `rows` in `cy`, but even if you added through `support.js` then cy functions return promises, check [this](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Assigning-Return-Values) for further info.
you have to use `.then` ([here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then.html#Syntax)) to access the cypress values i.e your code will be something like this

```
cy.contains("Lion").click();

cy.get('rows').then($rows => $rows.each((row) => {
  expect(row.text()).to.include("Lion");
}));
```

Comment: Yes of course, i´m using page objects and re-wrote the code to make it more easy to read. I added an. cy.get() instead

Comment: Does not work. I get the following error message when using your code: `cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.`